# Does magnesium deficiency cause sugar cravings?

Tags: nutrition

A number of websites claim that sugar cravings may be a sign of a magnesium deficiency.

For example: [Genesis Medical Scheme](https://www.genesismedical.co.za/10-supplements-that-may-curb-your-carb-cravings-and-help-you-lose-weight/) is one of many sites that carry an article that claims:

> Magnesium regulates glucose and insulin levels, as well as the neurotransmitter dopamine. **A deficiency will cause intense sugar cravings**, especially for chocolate.

Does magnesium deficiency lead to people craving sugar?

Comment: Nicely done for a first post, welcome to Skeptics dgo.

Comment: But, the link says *"Because chocolate is high in magnesium, it's been suggested that a deficiency may play a role in these cravings," she says. "This is a research area that needs more investigation, but it does present an intriguing possibility in terms of what might be the underlying cause of these cravings."* They say it is because chocolate contains the deficient mineral, not because it is sweet.

Comment: @WeatherVane - take a search.  That's just that article.  There are plenty.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) Let's see if we can find an actual claim. The one you quote is talking about a public health crisis of magnesium deficiency. The quoted expert hints that it would be interesting to research whether magnesium deficiency might maybe be behind *chocolate* cravings. You mention there are plenty of articles. Let's choose one of those to quote.

Comment: @Oddthinking.  Thanks.  That’s perfect.

Comment: Is this something for the medical sciences SE?